# Proper way to parse a date as UTC using date-fns

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, timezone, date-fns

I have a log file with some timestamps

```
2020-12-03 08:30:00
2020-12-03 08:40:00
...
```

I know from the log provider's documentation that the timestamps are written in UTC (although not using ISO format)

Now I want to [parse them with date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/parse) :

```
const toParse = "2020-12-03 08:40:00"
parse(toParse, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', new Date()).toISOString()
```

And because the locale of my computer is in UTC+1 here is what I see:

```
> "2020-12-03T07:40:00Z"
```

expected:

```
> "2020-12-03T08:40:00Z".
```

**Here is the hack I currently use to tell date-fns to parse as UTC :**

```
const toParse = "2020-12-03 08:40:00"
parse(toParse + '+00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' + 'X', new Date()).toISOString()
```

And as expected,

```
> "2020-12-03T08:40:00Z".
```

**Is there any proper way of doing this using date-fns? Looking for an equivalent to moment's `moment.utc()`**

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat
You know the offset to adjust the stored date to your time zone. Date-fns-tz has support for Intl.DateTimeFormat.

Comment: Either way you should indicate what timezone a datetime value has. You can sinplify your hack: `parseIso(toParse+'Z').toISOString()`

Comment: If "2020-12-03 08:40:00" is parsed as UTC +1, the Z time is 07:40:00Z, not 09:40. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know about "proper", but you can use [*zonedTimeToUtc*](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/Time-Zones#date-fns-tz) to treat a timestamp as having any offset or timezone you like, including UTC, e.g.

````
// Setup
var {parse} = require('date-fns');
var {zonedTimeToUtc} = require('date-fns-tz');

// Parse an ISO 8601 timestamp recognised by date-fns
let loc = 'UTC';
let s1   = '2020-12-03 08:30:00';
let utcDate =  zonedTimeToUtc(s1, loc);

// Show UTC ISO 8601 timestamp
console.log(utcDate.toISOString()); // "2020-12-03T08:30:00.000Z"

// Parse non–standard format yyyyMMdd
let s2 = '20210119';
let fIn = 'yyyyMMdd';
let d = zonedTimeToUtc(parse(s2, fIn, new Date()), loc);
console.log(d.toISOString()); // "2021-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"```
````

You can test it at [npm.runkit.com/date-fns](https://npm.runkit.com/date-fns).

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for! However your code does not make use of `fIn` (fortunately in this example it parses at UTC but the log could have a less friendly format). `zonedTimeToUtc(parse(s, fIn, new Date()), loc);` works.

Comment: @YannP—yes, if the format isn't one recognised by date-fns then you need to add *parse*. I find the requirement for a Date to always be passed to *parse* an inexplicable design decision.

Comment: Totally agree. I had to add a comment to my pull request to explain why it's "needed"...

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for [parseJSON](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/parseJSON), which supports a number of formats (but does not let you specify the source format).

> Converts a complete ISO date string in UTC time, the typical format for transmitting a date in JSON, to a JavaScript Date instance.

```
import { parseJSON } from 'date-fns';
const utcDate = parseJSON('2020-12-03 08:40:00');

// Thu Dec 03 2020 19:40:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Yes, `parseJSON` from `date-fns` finally worked! I got date strings from SQLite that are in UTC, without explicit timezone. Parsing those date strings using `date-fns` `parse` or vanilla JS `Date` resulted in a modified Date, as a non-UTC timezone was assumed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no need for date-fns-tz...

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `parseJSON('2020-12-03')` if you only have a date-only format.

Answer (score 3):

Example of using parse and zonedTimeToUtc

```
 it('should parse polish date', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1)
    const dateWithoutTime = '29 gru 2003'

    const parsed = parse(dateWithoutTime, 'd LLL yyyy', new Date(), {
      locale: pl,
    })

    const dateUTC = zonedTimeToUtc(parsed, 'UTC')

    expect(dateUTC.toISOString()).toStrictEqual('2003-12-29T00:00:00.000Z')
  })
```